# Equation of Parabola in Rosenbrock function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

The [Rosenbrock function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function) is a popular benchmark for optimization, its general form is
$$
f(x, y) = (a - x)^2 + b(y - x^2)^2
$$
where typically $a=1$ and $b=100$. The function looks like this

[image]

Is it possible to find the equation of the parabola that would fit within its contours? Here's a rough drawing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just $y=x^2$.

For any fixed $x$ value (i.e. vertical line), the bottom of the trough, where $f$ is minimal along that line, occurs where $\partial f/\partial y = 0$. And $\partial f/\partial y = 2b(y-x^2)$.

Comment: Well, the calculation says it is, but that's an interesting question, because it feels like it shouldn't be, right? Can you generate another plot, with smaller $b$ and larger $a$? The only way I can think to reconcile things is that maybe the shape of the canyon changes while the bottom of the trough stays in the same place, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Hmmm, my previous comment was in response to a comment (which was deleted, I guess) asking if this was independent of $a$. I still think that's a good question.